# Blazor Two JS Interop which depend on each other

Tags: blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I'm using two libraries which uses JS interop and depends on each other to be complete. One is BlazoredStyled for themeing, the other is a graph display.

```
App.razor
 OnInitializedAsync
    BlazoredStyled.SetThemeJS  // there is delay to set this up

Index.razor where I display graph
   OnInitializedAsync
      Graph.CreateJS           // delay to set this up
      Graph.SetTheme           // theme may not be ready
```

Since both JS have delay, I'm running into situation where either the graph is not ready or theme is not set. The other way I tried is set the theme after its loaded

```
App.razor
  OnInitialiedAsync
    BlazoredStyled.SetThemeJS  // delay to setup
    Graph.SetTheme             // this does not work either becos graph may not be setup
```

Since a blazor component lifetime is independent of another, how do I setup properly?

Comment: Is the theme going to change throughout the life of the app?  And how long does the call take that sets up the theme?

Comment: Yes, I have another component Select theme to change but that's a separate issue. It apparently takes quite a while, and I'm running into race condition sometimes.

Comment: Without a source repo it's not going to be easy to offer advice.

Comment: @Robin have you solved the issue yet?

Comment: It's been a while I stopped working on blazor. If I remember, I was told it's not solvable in githb so had to do workaround, I think I stopped using one of the libraries.